# Deutsche Aussprache von Boston

Tags: pronunciation, place-name

Der Duden (Das Aussprachewörterbuch, 2005) gibt folgende Aussprache von **Boston** an:

> [ˈbɔstɔn]

mit [ɔ] wie in Post [pɔst]. Im [Onlineduden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Boston_Stadt) findet man stattdessen die englische Variante

> [ˈbɔstən]

Erstere habe ich bisher im deutschen Sprachraum noch nie gehört. Stattdessen kommt mir hin und wieder die englische Originalaussprache unter, aber viel häufiger wird **Boston** als

> [ˈbɔstn]

ausgesprochen, insbesondere auch von Nachrichtensprechern (z. B. [hier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6VEOucdfNao)).

Das scheint konsistent mit der deutschen Aussprache von **Washington** zu sein (Original [ˈwɔʃɪŋtən], laut Duden Aussprachewörterbuch [ˈvɔʃɪŋtn], in der Praxis auch [ˈwɔʃɪŋtn] mit englischem [w]). Die Schwa-Elision wird gerne auch auf **London** angewandt ([lɔndn]), obwohl es im Original [‘lʌndən] und im Deutschen [‘lɔndɔn] heißt. Im Falle von **Boston** und **Washington** scheint die Schwa-Elision aber im Deutschen (!) üblich zu sein, und eine deutsche Aussprache dieser Namen zu definieren.

Meine Frage: Gibt der Duden eine falsche (d. h. in der Praxis unübliche) Aussprache von **Boston** an?

Comment: Man beachte allerdings, dass bei Ableitungen, etwa _Washingtoner Artenschutzabkommen_, das (hintere) _o_ doch wieder als /o/ oder /ɔ/ gesprochen wird, seltener als Schwa. Zu _Boston_ fällt mir (außer der Bezeichnung für die Bewohner) gerade kein gutes Beispiel ein – Boston-Marathon, Massaker von Boston, Boston Tea Party …

Answer (score 4):

Die deutsche Sprache wird nicht einheitlich ausgesprochen. Im Duden Band 6 – *Aussprachewörterbuch* wird die sogenannte *Standardlautung (Standardaussprache)* verwendet.

Laut *Aussprachewörterbuch* sind die wesentlichen Merkmale der Standardlautung:

> 1. Sie ist eine Gebrauchsnorm, die der Sprechwirklichkeit nahekommt. Sie erhebt jedoch keinen Anspruch darauf, die vielfältigen Schattierungen der gesprochenen Sprache vollständig widerzuspiegeln.
> 2. Sie ist überregional. Sie enthält keine typisch landschaftlichen Ausspracheformen.
> 3. Sie ist einheitlich. Varianten (freie Varianten und Phonemvarianten) werden ausgeschaltet oder auf ein Mindestmaß beschränkt.
> 4. Sie ist schriftnah, d. h., sie wird weitgehend durch das Schriftbild bestimmt.
> 5. Sie ist deutlich, unterscheidet die Laute einerseits stärker als die Umgangslautung, andererseits schwächer als die zu erhöhter Deutlichkeit neigende Bühnenaussprache.

Insbesondere der vierte Punkt erklärt, dass die Aussprache [ˈbɔstɔn] weitgehend durch das Schriftbild „Boston“ bestimmt wird.

Allerdings ist *Boston* kein deutsches Wort, sondern ein englischer Eigenname.
Laut *Aussprachewörterbuch* hängt die Aussprache nichteingedeutschter fremder Wörter – besonders Eigennamen – von verschiedenen Umständen ab:

> 1. Verbreitung einer Fremdsprache
> 2. Nachbarschaft einer Fremdsprache
> 3. Länge der Textteile
> 4. Wichtigkeit und Geltungsdauer der Wörter
> 5. Gesprächsgegenstand und das Verhältnis zwischen Sprecher und Hörer

Insbesondere der erste Punkt, d. h. die Verbreitung von Englisch als Fremdsprache im deutschen Sprachgebiet, führt dazu, den Namen *Boston* eher echt fremdsprachlich auszusprechen.

Folgerichtig findet man im *Aussprachewörterbuch* unter *Boston* neben der Standardlautung auch eine fremdsprachliche Aussprache:

> **Bọston** [ˈbɔstɔn] *engl.* [ˈbɔstən]

Comment: Vielen Dank, das ist sehr hilfreich. Allerdings scheint sich im Falle von Boston statt der originalen Aussprache eine halb-deutsche Variante durchgesetzt zu haben, siehe auch den Kommentar von @Hubert Schölnast oben.

Answer (score 1):

Falls im Duden tatsächlich [ˈbɔstɔn] stünde, würde ich deine Frage mit "ja" beantworten, aber das ist meinen Recherchen nach gar nicht der Fall. In meiner Ausgabe des Duden steht:

> 1 **Bos|ton** [...tn̩] (Stadt in England und in den USA)
>   2 **Bos|ton**, das: -s (ein Kartenspiel)
>   3 **Bos|ton**, der: -s, -s (ein Tanz)

Quelle:

DUDEN
Die deutsche Rechtschreibung
23. Auflage (2004)

Comment: Interessant. Im Aussprachewörterbuch von 2005 (und online) steht genau was ich oben geschrieben habe. Es scheint also, als ob der Duden in sich nicht konsistent ist. Danke für die Recherche.

Comment: In der 21. Auflage von "Die deutsche Rechtschreibung" steht [ˈbɔst(ə)n].

Answer (score -1):

Wer nicht Englisch kann, wird / boston/ (meine vereinfachte Lautschrift) sagen, ohne im Duden nachzuschauen, da aber viele Deutsche Englisch können, werden sie die englische Aussprache benutzen, mit oder ohne schwachem e am Ende. Und Radiosprecher benutzen heute meistens die landesübliche Aussprache.
Ich würde sagen, einen Fehler kannst du bei der deutschen Aussprache von Boston nicht machen, da gibt es keine Norm.